# How could I calculate the volume of n-dimensional cube (n >= 4)

Tags: geometry

I'm stucking with a programming problem that needs math to solve:

```
Given an positive number m and n-dimensional cube has sizes such as: a1,a2,a3,..an. Calculate its volume after modulo m.
```

I didn't know the formula to calculate this problem, and I searched for it on the Internet. Appreciate any answer.
Hopefully, you have a great day.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: When you say "cube", do you mean "cuboid", i.e. something like $n$-dimensional *rectangle/rectangular prism*, rather than a proper cube? The formula for the volume of the cuboid with dimensions $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$ is simply $V=a_1\times a_2\times\cdots\times a_n$.

Comment: Is such a product called a volume at all , if we have more than $3$ dimensions ?